# Can google pagespeed insight give wrong or cached results

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-pagespeed

I have different domains/subdomains with same CSS and loading practically same resources ..but from different databases.

www.landshoppe.com, navimumbai.landshoppe.com, thane.landshoppe.com, mumbai.landshoppe.com, konkan.landshoppe.com

However, all are showing same results of the google pagespeed insight desktop score and 90+ mobile score except for the second and last one for which the mobile scores are about 70. These two fail the google mobile friendly test too. It says some images are going out of the viewport. But if you see in a mobile, they are all very much within the viewport.

Is it sime inconsistency in Google Pagespeed Insight ? Is that possible ? That is all I want to know.

Comment: Well, please explain....I though this forum was to find answers to questions for which there was none found elsewhere on the net or stack overflow !! Please point me to relevant links if you know of any answer to this elsewhere ! I would have been breaking my head over this for ages if I didn't know whether it is my coding fault or google fault !!

Comment: The reasons why someone would downvote are visible if you hover over the down arrow...I don't know what more to tell you.

Comment: Google Pagespeed Insight should never been taken at face value and trying to achieve a "perfect" score is a fool's errand. It can be useful to show potential issues, but beyond that... it's pretty irrelevant. (no, I didn't down vote and the ranting about down voting is really unwarranted - bring it up on Meta if it bothers you).

Answer (score 1):

If I look at [Google's Mobile Friendly results](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=konkan.landshoppe.com&hl=en) for http://konkan.landshoppe.com/ it says in part that

> This page may appear not mobile-friendly because the robots.txt file
>   may block Googlebot from loading some of the page's resources

It's possible that this might be a problem ([see this Google link](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/common-mistakes?hl=en-US&utm_source=MFT&utm_campaign=MFT&utm_medium=incoming-link#blocked-resources) on how to troubleshoot) though the first thing I would look at is that you have a CSS file coming from http://www.landshoppe.com/domainfiles/linkcommon.css
 It's a different domain so I think it's likely the culprit.

Hope this helps!

**Update**:

Are you able to test what happens if, instead of loading http://www.landshoppe.com/domainfiles/linkcommon.css as you are on say konkan.landshoppe.com, you move a copy of this CSS file to http://konkan.landshoppe.com and load it from that domain?

I see some inconsistencies on how http://konkan.landshoppe.com is displayed in different browsers, and there's a connection with styles in the linkcommon.css file.

I agree that only the second and last domains fail the mobile-friendly test, but content on the 5 domains is different. And the 2 sites which fail have images which display too wide on some browsers, again, related to this linkcommon.css file

Comment: Thanks for the input David. You must have observed that  konkan.landshoppe.com is a subdomain of landshoppe.com like the others.  I have similar robots.txt and same link to css in all those domains. Yet, only two seem to have some issues.

Comment: In fact webmaster tools blocked resources report for the site says there are  'no blocked resources' !